# pandas groupby.agg to list behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Can someone help me understand what's going on here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "alive", "Data"], 
                  data=[
                      [154887124, True, "Data1"],
                      [154887124, True, "Data2"],
                      [159320850, True, "Data3"],
                      [159320850, True, "Data4"],
                      [159320849, True, "Data5"]                      
                  ])
df = df.groupby(['ID','alive']).agg({'Data': lambda x: x.tolist()})
df
```

Which outputs this:

```
                              Data
       ID   alive   
----------------------------------
154887124   True    [Data1, Data2]
159320849   True    [Data5]
159320850   True    [Data3, Data4]
```

My goal is to group by the ID and alive columns, and then concatenate the Data column into a list.  The above code works correctly, however it moves the "Data" column header "up" a row above the other 2 column names for some reason.

From a strictly cosmetic perspective, this is fine, I can reference the values in the Data column without issue, the problem is I have a 2nd dataframe in the exact same format, only the data in the "Data" column is already in a list, and I need to concat this to it.  However, the concat statement doesn't match up the "Data" columns in the 2 dataframes, and the only difference I can see is on the 2nd dataframe ID, alive, and Data are all on the same "row" in the header.

Why does my groupby.agg function function dot his to the dataframe?

---

update

Ok, this appears to be creating a multiIndex for some reason, and this appears to correct it:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
```

However, I'm still curious why the groupby.agg creates a multiindex like this?

Comment: the groupby result sorted by id

Comment: same result by adding sort=False to the groupby.  Only difference is the results aren't sorted.

Comment: after the groupby, id and alive in the index, 'data' is the column name. They are where they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected, after groupby by default is created `index` or `MultiIndex` from columns inside `groupby`, for prevent it is possible use `as_index=False` parameter or `.reset_index()`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','alive'], as_index=False).agg({'Data': lambda x: x.tolist()})
#alternative
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','alive']).agg({'Data': lambda x: x.tolist()}).reset_index()
```

Or is possible simplify your solution:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','alive'], as_index=False)['Data'].agg(list)
#alternative
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','alive'], as_index=False)['Data'].agg(list)
```

---

```
print (df1)
          ID  alive            Data
0  154887124   True  [Data1, Data2]
1  159320849   True         [Data5]
2  159320850   True  [Data3, Data4]
```